# WPF - Element's colour is bound to button, but doesn't update on button state change

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have the following `button` with the `label` inside whose `foreground color` I wish to bind to the `button`'s:

```
<Button x:Name="login_button" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Template="{DynamicResource TileTemplate}"
         Margin="5,10,5,10">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/textures/logos/lock.png"
               VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0"
               Margin="10,10,10,10">
        </Image>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
               HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"
               Content="LOG IN" FontSize="40" FontFamily="CenturyGothicRegual"
               Margin="10,10,10,10">
            <Label.Foreground>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding ElementName=login_button, Path=BorderBrush.Color,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                     Opacity="{Binding ElementName=login_button, Path=BorderBrush.Opacity,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </Label.Foreground>
        </Label>
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

The button gets coloured using a `template`:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="TileTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">

        <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="#99C3C3C3" BorderThickness="2">
            <Border.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#28B6B6B6" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#424D4D4D" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Border.Background>
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#42B2B2B2"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#28FFFFFF"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#7F5B5B5B"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#42B2B2B2"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#28FFFFFF"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFD1A139"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Offset)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Offset)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.8"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFF0A300"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#5991774A"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#28FFFFFF"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Offset)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.004"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.8"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <Grid>
                <ContentPresenter/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

I do not know if the template is important, I just enclosed it in case it is. The problem is that while the label **does** receive the button's colour at start, but when the button's state changes, like `MouseOver` or `Clicked`, the label's colour remains the same even if I added the `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` in the binding. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VisualStates that you define in the `ControlTemplate` doesn't apply to the `Button`'s Content.

You could define the brushes or colour as stand-alone resources and apply them both in your `ControlTemplate` and in a `Style` for the `Label`:

```
<Color x:Key="moColor">#FFD1A139</Color>
...
<ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource moColor}"/>
</ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

---

```
<Button x:Name="login_button" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Template="{DynamicResource TileTemplate}" Margin="5,10,5,10">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/textures/logos/lock.png"
                   VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0"
                   Margin="10,10,10,10">
        </Image>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                   HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"
                   Content="LOG IN" FontSize="40" FontFamily="CenturyGothicRegual"
                   Margin="10,10,10,10">
            <Label.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Label">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource moColor}" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.8" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Label.Style>
        </Label>
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

Comment: I didn't use it this clean for fearing that I mess things up so I changed a bit :D but now it works. Thank for your help!